# How to handle response & error in Angular JS service with typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am using angular js to call my wcf service that returns some data. Now if my wcf service throws exception I want to handle that accordingly. 
My flow of call in angular is like this:
My page controller calls the angular service which calls my wcf service using $http.
My Controller:

```
setProfileStatus: (status: boolean) => 
{
 angularService.setProfileStatus(status).then(
response => {
     //my response is always undefined.
     console.log(response.data);         
  })
.catch(err => {
       //show error
}); 
}
```

In my above controller when I call my service my response is always undefined.
Here is my service:

```
public setProfileStatus(status: boolean): ng.IPromise<any> {
 var url = this._endpoints.myEndpoint + '?status=' + status;
 return this._http.put<string>(url, '').then(response => {
//response here is fine, I can get data also and any error but I want to pass this to my controller
 });
}
```

In my above service call I can get the response fine, with any data that was returned from my wcf service.
So how to pass this to my controller so that same response I can see in my controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get most of the [IQservice](http://definitelytyped.org/docs/angularjs--angular/interfaces/ng.iqservice.html)

```
export class CaseFieldService {
    // Inject `ng.IQservice` to your `ProfileService`
    constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService, private $q: ng.IQService) {
    }

    public setProfileStatus(status: boolean): ng.IPromise<any> {
        // Create deferred 
        var d = this.$q.defer();            

        // resolve promise on success
        this.$http.put<string>(url, '')
            .success(response => d.resolve(response))
            .error(err => d.reject(err));

        // return promise
        return d.promise;
    }
}
```

In your controller method use service and add `then`:

```
private saveProfile(): void {

    this._profileService.setProfileStatus(true)
        .then(
               (result: any) => {
                  // success: use result value here
               }, 
               (error: any) => {
                   // error: handle error here
               }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks max. This works and I can get data from the response.  But say my throws error how to handle that. If any exception occurs in the above method call I am adding some status code to the outgoing response. Say I am adding "Internal server error" to the outgoing response. I added .catch(err => { } to my controller after then but this again never gets hits. In my catch I want to see the status code and then act accordingly

Comment: how would you cancel execution after the error. Let's say you have another then after that then.